# Excel: AND, IF, OR function

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I would like is TRUE to be returned when:
B3>1000 and C3>30 when either 2 of the 4 columns G3, H3, I3 or J3 >106 and when either 2 of the 3 columns M3, N3 or O3 <100.

I have this but it is incomplete and it fails to grasp the 2/4 element and the 2/3 element:

```
=IF(AND(OR(G3>106,H3>106,I3>106,J3>106),B3>1000,D3>30),"TRUE","TRUE")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to break it down into 3 components,

Wrap them within an `OR`, as any can be `TRUE` to return an overall `TRUE`,

Or wrap in an `AND` if they all need to be `TRUE`

```
=OR(  AND(B3>100,C3>30)=TRUE,     COUNTIF(G3:J3,">"&100)>1,     COUNTIF(M3:O3,">"&100)>1   )
```

Comment: COUNTIF(G3:J3,">"&100)>1  Is this saying that G3:J3 must be over 100 and that from G3:J3 more than 1 of them meet this condition?

Comment: sorry, that should be 106, and it saying if either of the 2 columns are greater than 106 then return TRUE

Comment: Wilga, the `COUNTIF()` counts how many times G3:J3 is >106 and if that count is >1, then the expression is TRUE.  Peter, `=TRUE` isn't necessary, and the conditions are `>106` and `<100`.  Also, from OP's formula, it may be that the several conditions need to be `AND`ed.  If that's true, try: `=AND(B3>100,C3>30,COUNTIF(G3:J3,">"&106)>1,COUNTIF(M3:O3,"<"&100)>1)`.

Comment: Since OP query is 2 out of 4 >106 and 2 of 3 <100. So in this case little correction is required and it  should be,  =AND(B3>100,C3>30,COUNTIF(G3:J3,">"&106)=2,COUNTIF(M3:O3,"<"&100)=2). Because if is >1 then Excel returns TRUE if 3 or even all are >106 and the similar with <100. I've tested with both >1 and =2 and found =2 is perfectly working, and it's the query.